# Magento 2 order view errors

Tags: magento2.3.4-p2

[image]

When I am tryied to see the orders this errors shows

Comment: Confirm the table name use into the query, they are exist into the database or not.

Comment: Remove your thirdparty module, or fix that module

Comment: The table name is exist in the database even i disable the module i got same error @Dhiren Vasoya

Comment: run the cache command and then check.

Comment: Actually I overrinding the  history.phtml file

Comment: Actually bro sales_order_addcomment is not present in database @ Dhiren Vasoya

Comment: And that why the above error show to you.

Answer (score 0):

The error mentions a table that is not part of a Magento2 default installation, check which module/files are using it and disable/remove its code:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @SantiBM I slove that error